# Расширение chrome на сервере

Tags: php, javascript, ubuntu, сервер, расширения

Вопрос, можно ли как-то запустить расширение, чтобы оно 24/7 работало, если есть Ubuntu сервер, может есть варианты через PHP или JS например? Нужно чтобы расширение постоянно парсило страничку, так как через PHP до нее не добраться по неизвестным причинам. Вот этот json нужен http://cs.money/load_all_bots_inventory

Comment: Странно, решение вопроса про расширение не знаю. На php: есть несколько способов полутень нужные вам данные (curl, file-get). Советую поиграться с эмуляцией браузера curlом

Comment: Очевидно что запустить расширение для браузера на сервере нельзя. Разве что на машину сервера установить браузер и там запустить расширение. Но это слишком глупо, ибо тогда лучше ноду использовать. А `PHP` отлично добирается до Вашей ссылки, у Вас, видимо, какие-то проблемы с доступом (забанили из-за парсинга?).

Comment: @Other скорее всего забанили, так как у меня он не добирается, хотя прописываю все правильно и другие сайты у меня парсит без проблем, спасибо всеровно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вы имеете ввиду под фразой "не добраться"?

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://cs.money/load_all_bots_inventory'), true);
print_r($data);
```

никаких проблем

Comment: Именно это и имею ввиду, при использовании просто отобразит ничего, или мы прям проверили, что он работает?

Comment: @100РОЖЬ конечно проверил